# Google Cloud run failed to start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to deploy a container to cloud run, but my deploy fails because of this error:

```
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Locally my container is able to start and I can see this log (phoenix app):

```
19:54:51.487 [info] Running ProjectWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.7.0 at 0.0.0.0:8080 (http)
```

When I add to my docker run invocation -p 8080:8080, I can see that `curl localhost:8080/health` returns a 200 response.

```
curl localhost:8080/health
[{"error":null,"healthy":true,"name":"NOOP","time":12}]
```

What's strange is that in Cloud Run and Cloud Logging, I don't see any of my container logs, even though I see them locally and I know that I have logs that should be outputting to stdout and stderr on start up, so debugging is super hard.

What could be causing the logging issue? Why is Cloud Run able to talk to my container's server?

Comment: I've tried deploying a demo container provided by Google. That deployment was successful, so I don't think this is related to my account's configuration or permissions.

Comment: Do you have more logs trace into stackdriver logging? Can you share your code?

Comment: Why are you mentioning the `/health` endpoint here? FYI, this is not what Cloud Run uses to determine whether your container has started.

Comment: @babaloo From what you said things look good. Assuming you're using Elixir, can you try the Elixir sample? https://github.com/knative/docs/tree/master/community/samples/serving/helloworld-elixir Technically we only check if container is reachable on its external network interface on PORT (:8080). I wonder 0.0.0.0 means something different for Elixir.

Comment: DustinIngram: Just verifying my server is still up. Though, how does cloud run check container health?
guillaumeblaquiere: I don't have any specific cloud logging integrations beyond relying on my container's stdout logs to be ingested.
AhmetB-Google: I do see some questions about that as well online. Will try sample.

I tried adding debug logs before and after my server invocation in my docker-entrypoint and stopped seeing logs after my server started. I'm not sure why my server would behave differently in my local container vs cloud run.

Comment: Please include the `gcloud run deploy ...` command too. In my experience, the `Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable` is more often   related to other configuration issues and **not** the PORT environment variable. If the container doesn't start, you're not going to get logs. Where is the container image and can Cloud Run access it?

Comment: In addition, I would like to provide you [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) documentation for troubleshooting your Cloud Run.

Comment: I'm using this dockerfile: https://github.com/mirego/elixir-boilerplate/blob/master/Dockerfile with a fresh phoenix application. 
The container does start locally on my workstation. I think cloud run is able to access it, since otherwise I would have expected to see cloud run fail to find the container instead of saying that it started it.